# Is overwriting variables names for lengthy operations bad style?

Tags: python, pandas, pep8

I quite often find myself in a situation where I undertake several steps to get from my start data input to the output I want to have, e.g. in functions/loops. To avoid making my lines very long, I sometimes overwrite the variable name I am using in these operations.

One example would be:

```
df_2 = df_1.loc[(df1['id'] == val)]
df_2 = df_2[['c1','c2']]
df_2 = df_2.merge(df3, left_on='c1', right_on='c1'))
```

The only alternative I can come up with is:

```
df_2 = df_1.loc[(df1['id'] == val)][['c1','c2']]\
    .merge(df3, left_on='c1', right_on='c1'))
```

But none of these options feels really clean. how should these situations be handled?

Comment: Another option would be to use separate variables for the indices, so you can (ultimately) write `df_2 = df_1.loc[x][y].merge(...)`, with `x` and `y` referring to the `==` test and the index list, respectively. I don't think there's any one approach that is right for all situations; it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this article](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#methodchaining) which discusses exactly your question.

> The pandas core team now **encourages** the use of "method chaining".
> This is a style of programming in which you chain together multiple
> method calls into a single statement. This allows you to pass
> intermediate results from one method to the next rather than storing
> the intermediate results using variables.

In addition to prettifying the chained codes by using brackets and indentation like @perl's answer, you might also find using functions like [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) useful for coding in a "method chaining" style.

Of course, there are some drawbacks for method chaining, especially when excessive:

> "One drawback to excessively long chains is that **debugging can be
> harder**. If something looks wrong at the end, you don't have
> intermediate values to inspect."

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option, you can put everything in brackets and then break the lines, like this:

```
df_2 = (df_1
            .loc[(df1['id'] == val)][['c1','c2']]
            .merge(df3, left_on='c1', right_on='c1')))
```

It's generally pretty readable even if you have a lot of lines, and if you want to change the name of the output variable, you only need to change it in one place. So, a bit less verbose, and a bit easier to make changes to as compared to overwriting the variables